# Syntax differences between Tampermonkey and Greasemonkey?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I've been trying to transfer a lot of my Tampermonkey (in Google Chrome) userscripts to Greasemonkey in FireFox. Unfortunately, it seems that they don't work properly when I transfer them into Greasemonkey - I'm assuming there are syntactical differences, but I'm not sure what they are, nor have I found great information regarding the differences.

This code for instance:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     DailySearch
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @include  *
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM_openInTab
// ==/UserScript==

//--- Note that the contains() text is case-sensitive.
var TargetLink = $("a:contains('Daily Search')")

if (TargetLink.length)
    GM_openInTab (TargetLink[0].href);
```

This works in Tampermonkey on Chrome but not in Greasemonkey. What differences lie between the two, and how can I get this to work in FireFox?

Comment: Why?  Just use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey on Firefox.

Comment: I guess I'll just spare myself Greasemonkey since I'm used to using Tampermonkey anyway in Chrome. Thanks for the response and reminding me to keep it simple haha.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of GM are you using?
GM4 uses `GM.openInTab` (GM3 used `GM_openInTab`)
`GM_addStyle` was dropped in GM4 (https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_addStyle)